# Can't change background color to ContentView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change the background color for ContentView in my project, I tried grouping all together inside a ZStack and setting the background color before anything else, I tried using `.background` modifier in my VStack, but none is working, here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var chatViewModel = ChatView.ChatViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TabView {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChatView(chatId: chatViewModel.currentChatId)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Ask me anything")
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 80)
                            .background(Gradient(colors: [.red, .purple, .blue]))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
                    }
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        let newChat = Chat(messages: [Message(role: .system, content: "Hi, I'm your personal assistant, ask me anything!", createdAt: Date())])
                        chatViewModel.chats.append(newChat)
                        chatViewModel.currentChatId = newChat.id
                    })
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Chat", systemImage: "bubble.left")
                    }
                    ChatHistoryView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Chat history", systemImage: "clock")
                        }
                    MoreView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("More", systemImage: "text.justify")
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Back")
            .background(Color.black)
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        }
        .environmentObject(chatViewModel)
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you create inside the `TabView` is what is taking up the whole screen, so that is where the background needs to be applied. See code for simple background of `Color.purple`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var chatViewModel = ChatView.ChatViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TabView {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChatView(chatId: chatViewModel.currentChatId)
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.purple
                                .ignoresSafeArea() // <--- here!!!!!
                            Text("Ask me anything")
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 80)
                                .background(Gradient(colors: [.red, .purple, .blue]))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
                        }
                        }
                       
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        let newChat = Chat(messages: [Message(role: .system, content: "Hi, I'm your personal assistant, ask me anything!", createdAt: Date())])
                        chatViewModel.chats.append(newChat)
                        chatViewModel.currentChatId = newChat.id
                    })
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Chat", systemImage: "bubble.left")
                    }
                    ChatHistoryView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Chat history", systemImage: "clock")
                        }
                    MoreView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("More", systemImage: "text.justify")
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Back")
            .background(Color.black)
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        }
        .environmentObject(chatViewModel)
    }

    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```